# What characters does php use for high base numbers?

Tags: php, base-conversion

I know that base 16 uses the characters [0-9a-f], and base 36 uses [0-9a-z], but what about base 40? Base 50? Base [arbitrary number]? How does php determine what characters to use for high-base numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP won't "determine" symbols for just any arbitrary base. Because [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/base_convert) allows conversions for bases between `2` and `36` only. Thus, it's not allowed to use it for base 50, for example:

> Both frombase and tobase have to be between 2 and 36, inclusive.
>   Digits in numbers with a base higher than 10 will be represented with
>   the letters a-z, with a meaning 10, b meaning 11 and z meaning 35.

*I assume that it **is** about `base_convert()` since only this function has direct relation to the question*

As for `base_convert()`: [internally](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/math.c#1029), it will do [`_php_math_zvaltobase()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/math.c#_php_math_zvaltobase) call where char map is defined:

```
static char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```